# "Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined" when trying to use a worker in Papa Parse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I have a react app that streams data from a csv file. The relevant function looks like this:

```
loadCSV(url){
  Papa.parse(csv, 
             {download: true, 
              worker: true, 
              step: row => 
                    {this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, row.data]})}});}
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:1881)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:1891)
at __webpack_require__ (index.js:30)
at index.js:73
at index.js:76
at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (index.js:3)
at Object../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/react-error-overlay/lib/index.js (index.js:10)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f5513196fd3608c5177f:678)
at fn (bootstrap f5513196fd3608c5177f:88)
at Object../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js (webpackHotDevClient.js:24)
```

The error seems to be due to the "worker: true" line, because it works when I remove that. After some Googling, it seems that using workers can cause issues when making react apps with "create-react-app", but I'm really confused about what the proper solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Window and document object are not available in node env .  if you are running on server then you have to add check for client and server.